# Multitest p-values are different compared to graphpad prism?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, statsmodels, anova

I have a dataframe with the columns: Time, ID, Drug, Value

Here is my code on how i perform two-way anova and multipletests

```
#libraries
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests
import os

df= pd.read_excel(r"C:path.xlsm", sheet_name="test") #dataframe

order = [18,19,20,21,22,23,0] #sort 24 hour time starting at time 18hr

df['Drug']=pd.Categorical(df['Drug'])
df['Time'] = pd.Categorical(df['Time'], categories=order)

#TWO-WAY ANOVA
mod = sm.ols('Value~Drug+Time+Time*Drug', data = df).fit()
aov = anova_lm(mod, type=2)

#Multi-test (mt)
mt = pd.concat([mod.params,mod.pvalues],axis=1)
mt.columns=['coefficient','pvalues']
mt = mt[mt.index.str.contains('Drug')]
mt['corrected_p'] = multipletests(mt['pvalues'],alpha=0.05,method="sidak",is_sorted=True)[1]
```

I get the following uncorrected['pvalues' and correct pvalues['corrected_p'] from the output of multi-test (mt):

```
Index                  pvalues   correct_p
Drug[T.B]              0.0159475 0.106432
Time[T.19]:Drug[T.B]   0.0738362 0.41546     
Time[T.20]:Drug[T.B]   0.0778909 0.43314 
Time[T.21]:Drug[T.B]   0.0699678 0.398153
```

When i use the same dataset in graphpad prism i get these values instead (using two-way anova and multicomparison sidak:

```
Drug A-B   Individual P value Adjusted P Value
18         0.0159             0.1064
19         0.9689             >0.999
20         >0.9999            >0.999
21         0.9379             >0.999
```

Especially for time 19,20 and 21 the adjusted P-value are signficantly different and I'm not sure why. I'm concerned if i coded my statistics incorrectly causing the difference.

Happy to provide further info as needed

Comment: What are the uncorrected pbalues `mt['pvalues']`?

Comment: uncorrect pvalues from mt['pvalues'] are 0.0159475, 0.0738362, 0.0778909, 0.0699678 in the same order Drug[T.B],Time[T.19]:Drug[T.B], Time[T.20]:Drug[T.B], Time[T.21]:Drug[T.B]. I'll add this to the question

Comment: aside is_sorted should be left at False if pvalues are not already sorted.

Comment: Are the unadjusted pvalues the same in graphpad prism? Sidak is just a simultaneous adjustment of pvalues like bonferroni, There should not be a jump in p-values like `>0.999`.  My guess is that graphpad is interpreting the interaction differently than what you have in your statsmodels version. (I don't know anything about graphpad prism.)

Comment: One possible difference: maybe graphpad prism uses the number of all possible interactions as the relevant number of tests, while statsmodels uses only the number of pvalues in the list.

Comment: Thank you, the unadjusted pvalues from prism are updated in the question too. Ill ask them how about their sidak test. I've also replaced is_sorted to false and it didnt make a difference. Does having the categories for 'Time' in order make a difference to the calculation? 

`order = [18,19,20,21,22,23,0]
, df['Time'] = pd.Categorical(df['Time'], categories=order)`

Comment: For Sidak and Bonferroni, the order does not matter, those simultaneously adjust all p-values. Step-down or Step-up procedures need the order, but the only order that is relevant, is the sorting of p-values. How p-values are computed is not relevant for the p-value multiple testing correction in these methods.

Comment: Just to update this, you were correct in comment 3 and 4, the method i set in graphpad uses all interactions. once i changed the settings, i now get very similar results. Thanks for clarifying