# R AOV giving different p-values compared to graphpad prism?

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, anova

I'm running an ANOVA in R using aov, so I can analyze a lot of data at once. I've picked out a few samples to ensure accuracy, and my prism p-values are different than the ones I'm getting in R. My ANOVA in prism is not repeated measures.

I saw this question:

[Multitest p-values are different compared to graphpad prism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284098/multitest-p-values-are-different-compared-to-graphpad-prism)

But I'm not using statsmodel/python.

In R in doing:

```
analy$genotype <- as.character(for.analy$genotype)
analy$diet <- as.character(for.analy$diet)
analy$gene <- as.numeric(for.analy$gene)

interaction <- aov(gene ~ diet*genotype, data = analy)
summary(interaction)
```

This gives me:

```
              Df    Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
diet           1     34164    34164   0.012 0.9121  
genotype       1       261      261   0.000 0.9923  
diet:genotype  1  12808573 12808573   4.611 0.0361 *
Residuals     56 155556948  2777803
```

While in graphpad prism I get:

```
ANOVA table SS (Type III)   DF  MS      F (DFn, DFd)        P value
    Interaction 2852813     1   2852813 F (1, 56) = 1.043   P=0.3115
    Diet        12752869    1   12752869F (1, 56) = 4.663   P=0.0351
    Genotype    60058       1   60058   F (1, 56) = 0.02196 P=0.8827
    Residual    153146125   56  2734752
```

Thanks!

Comment: *(Type III)* is relevant

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/1.0-9/topics/Anova ; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/how-does-one-do-a-type-iii-ss-anova-in-r-with-contrast-codes

Comment: Are you saying I used use Type III ANOVA instead of AOV? Also, if you know, does AOV automatically assume the ANOVA type?                                       https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aov

Comment: The graphpad results you share has the text "ANOVA table SS (Type III)" . The links that I share provide r functions for type 3 anova.  You should try that and see if the results correspond.